# angularjs ui-select set default value and can not select the default value

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I follow the example in the angularjs ui-select bootstrap website.

**Here is the html part code:**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices group-by="'country'" repeat="item in ctrl.people | filter: $select.search">
          <span ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
          <small ng-bind-html="item.email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
```

**And here is the js part code:**

```
  $scope.person = {};

$scope.people = [
{ name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, country: 'United States' },
{ name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, country: 'Argentina' },
{ name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, country: 'Argentina' },
{ name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21, country: 'Ecuador' },
{ name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'Ecuador' },
{ name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'United States' },
{ name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43, country: 'Colombia' },
{ name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54, country: 'Ecuador' },
{ name: 'Michael',   email: 'michael@email.com',   age: 15, country: 'Colombia' },
{ name: 'Nicolás',   email: 'nicolas@email.com',    age: 43, country: 'Colombia' }];

  addoptions();
  function addoptions(){

     var tmp = { name: 'Nis',   email: 'nis@email.com',    age: 43, country: 'China' };
     $scope.people.push(tmp);
     var tmp2 = {name: 'Emma',   email: 'Emma@email.com',    age: 43, country: 'China'};
     $scope.people.push(tmp2);
     $scope.person.selected = $scope.people[0]; 
  }
```

The dropdown list should be look like the right side, but my just look like the left sie:

[image]

Also, I noticed one thing, once I set default person.select, the $$haskkey of 
`$scope.people[0]`, does not exist anymore.
My version of ui select is 0.17.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your issue and made a example where I cannot reproduce this issue. Could you check if you are having 0.17.1 or 0.17.2. In 0.17.2 they have made some changes where the selected value default is gone.
Here's [the example link](http://plnkr.co/SlZfHuGWjk6pfmo8yZtq)

```
 -
```

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that this is the version problem, and use 0.16.0 instead